# Set up usage analysis out of App Center and App Insights

Tags: ios, azure, analytics, azure-application-insights, visual-studio-app-center

So we have **an iOS client integrated with App Center**. We have also turned on **export into App Insights**. The goal is simple - implement Log Analytics queries to understand usage patterns, like

- most popular screens
- time spent on a screen per session
- time spent on a screen Y by users from location X
- what screen is the last one before people exit and so forth

An alternative would be to make data appearing at "Analysis of Page Views" tab in App Insights.

So when and how to generate events on the client to make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your app integrated with Appcenter SDK, You can set up custom events in your app.
Please see this link for [ios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/analytics/ios#custom-events) on how to set up custom events.

On App center portal , on the Analytics overview page, among other usage and engagement metrics, you can get details on [Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/analytics/overview#engagement) such as Session duration: Distribution of the number of sessions over a few duration intervals, Daily sessions per user: Daily average number of sessions per user.

When you export Analytics data to Application Insights, you can segment your audience refer to [usage-segmentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-segmentation#querying-for-certain-users) and also you can analyze the [user flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-flows)

Hamsa

Comment: Well that's not what I'm looking for. I need exactly what I've described in the question.